# framerate flash loader issuse

Tags: flash, loader

I have the next problem:

My main application loads different external swf into the Loader component. All those external swf have different frameRate but it inherits the frameRate of main application that is the problem.
My idea was to get the frameRate of the loaded swf and change the frameRate of main stage according to loaded value. But I didn't find any way how I can do it.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get loaded SWF's bytes, you can parse header to get frameRate. There are lot of such parsers ready, for example [this](http://simplistika.com/parsing-reading-swf-header/).